# Error while compiling OpenCV in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, compiling, opencv, v4l

I followed the instructions for compiling opencv2.4.9 from [Install OpenCV 2.4.9 in Ubuntu 14.04, 13.10](http://www.sysads.co.uk/2014/05/install-opencv-2-4-9-ubuntu-14-04-13-10/)

I am getting the following error during the build process. Can someone point out to me how to fix it?

```
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libopencv_highgui.a(cap_libv4l.cpp.o): undefined reference to symbol 'v4l2_munmap'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l2.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/opencv_test_highgui] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_highgui.dir/all] Error 2
```

Comment: Are you fulfilling all the pre-requisites to build this software ? Is the package `libv4l-dev` installed on your system ?

Comment: Yes it is installed, I read some where that this kind of DSO missing error is related to missing entries in the ld command in the makefile, however I am not sure where I can find the linker entry as I couldn't find any in the toplevel makefile

Comment: Hmm, is there are specific need for version 2.4.9? If it helps, the repositories have the OpenCV package (2.4.8) if you're just after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earlier I had downloaded the source as a zip file from the link on opencv website, this failed to build with the above error.

I checked out the source using git and followed the instructions from http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html

I still got the same errors, found this solution as a work around. you need to add -lv4l2 to the file mentioned in the link below

http://code.opencv.org/issues/3726